# MySQL sum and distinct on another column with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

I need to write a MySQL query that gives me stats about a defined user. Let's say I need sells, number of groups he joined, and number of friends he got.

```
SELECT  SUM( sells.qtty ) sells,
        SUM( sells.price ) total,
        COUNT( DISTINCT groups.id ) groupsTotal,
        COUNT( DISTINCT friends.id ) friendsTotal
FROM members
LEFT JOIN   sells
    ON      sells.idmember  = members.id
LEFT JOIN   groups
    ON      groups.idmember = members.id
LEFT JOIN   friends
    ON      friends.idmember    = members.id
where members.id = 3
```

Let's say that gives me 40 groups and 20 friends. I can't use distinct on sells table's ID column. So the sums gives me insane amount of sells (which would be nice if real, but not when trying to display stats).

I'm very confused here... Thanks ahead for any help !

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the aggregations before the joins.  One way is using subqueries in the `from` clause:

```
select  s.sells, s.total, g.groupsTotal, f.friendsTotal
from members m left outer join
     (select s.idmember, sum(s.qtty) as sells, sum(s.price) as total
      from sells s
      where s.idmember = 3
     ) s
     ON s.idmember  = m.id left outer join
     (select g.idmember, count(*) as groupstotal
      from groups g
      where g.idmember = 3
     ) g
     on g.idmember = m.id left outer join
     (select f.idmember, count(*) as friendstotal
      from friends
      where f.idmember = 3
     ) f
     on f.idmember  = m.id
where m.id = 3;
```

Typically, the `where` clauses in the subquery would instead by `group by`.  But you are only choosing one member, so it is more efficient to filter in each subquery.

Comment: I tried something like this, it's actually the best solution I have found ATM without calling the DB twice. The problem is, in one of the real queries, I haven't the member's ID, I only can use the group by command, and then lose the index in the derived table (according to explain the table is fully read). I guess the most efficient way will be to make two calls to DB...

Comment: @JeremyBelolo . . . There may be a way to do it in one query.  My suggestion would be to ask another question, with a sample query closer to what your real problem is.

Comment: I may have tried to simplify it too much... Thanks again.